# Pcolormesh changes graph after setting x and y

Tags: python, matplotlib

After adding x and y scale the graph view changes (x and y are equidistant). Without ading x and y scale the graph is correct and I don't know why.
Correct programm without scales:

```
df=pd.read_csv('file',header=[0,1],index_col=0)
columns=list(df.columns.levels[0])
F=np.array(df[columns[1]].columns[:-2])
F=F.astype(float)
i=1
plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(df[columns[i]].iloc[:,0:-2])
plt.colorbar(shrink=0.8)
plt.show(block=False)
```

When I add now the scales for to graph (df[columns[i]].iloc[:,-1]= 30.5,30.505,30.51, ... ,33.5;F=400,400.5,...,1100) The graph changes totally (It looks like a zoom in of the previous graph)
Programm with scales:

```
...
 plt.pcolormesh(Frequenzen,df[columns[i]].iloc[:,-1],df[columns[i]].iloc[:,0:-2])
... (all other stuff stays the same)
```

My data does not contain any nan values. Where is my problem?

Comment: Apologies, I'm not 100% sure of your problem here, but you possibly want to set the aspect ratio of the axes to be equal? `plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')`

Comment: Does not work (same result)